# iOS : Hide status bar in entire app programmatically not even through plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, statusbar

I want to hide status bar in my entire app.

Also I know it too, that we can do it by this way :

```
set the key value "View controller-based status bar appearance" NO in plist.
```

But I need to do the same only for iOS 7, so of course there need some condition for OS version and as of my knowledge we can not apply any condition in .plist file.

So anyone please suggest some line of code which only hide status bar for iOS 7.

Appreciate on your response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//Checking iOS version
 float versionOS;
 versionOS=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
  if(versionOS>=7.0)
   {
         [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES
   }
```

Add this code into `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Comment: It works while we check iOS version condition in AppDelegate class and hides only for iOS 7.

Answer (score 5):

add the following code to your view controllers:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

this will not disturb any ios below 7 because it is only called in ios7.

Comment: I have tried with this, but method is not getting called in iOS 7 also.

Comment: Got the solution, I have put this [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES; code for iOS 7 condition in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method I've found for hiding the status bar throughout the entire app is by creating creating a category on UIViewController and overriding prefersStatusBarHidden. This way you don't have to write this method in every single view controller.

## UIViewController+HideStatusBar.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (HideStatusBar)

@end
```

## UIViewController+HideStatusBar.m

```
#import "UIViewController+HideStatusBar.h"

@implementation UIViewController (HideStatusBar)

//Pragma Marks suppress compiler warning in LLVM. 
//Technically, you shouldn't override methods by using a category, 
//but I feel that in this case it won't hurt so long as you truly 
//want every view controller to hide the status bar. 
//Other opinions on this are definitely welcome

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop


@end
```